# Почему не работает мультитач?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch, multi-touch

Пишу программу на Java для android. С помощью startondrag двигаю ImageView. Во время перетаскивания картинки срабатывает событие onDrag, а когда отпускаю картинку срабатывает событие onDrop. Так вот вопрос, почему вовремя перетаскивания, когда выполняется событие onDrag - не работает multitouch?